# Angular Material custom theme error during ng serve: $color: null is not a color. --mat-mdc-button-ripple-color: #{rgba($color, 0.1)};

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to define a custom theme for my Angular project.
I am using:
Node 18.18.2
npm 10.2.1
Angular 16.2.10 (Angular CLI: 16.2.8)

I have tried to follow the Angular Material theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Here is my custom theme file: src/csn-theme.scss:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$primary-palette: (
    50: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.1),
    100: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.2),
    200: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.4),
    300: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.6),
    400: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.8),
    500: rgb(113, 120, 227),
    600: rgba(85, 90, 171),
    700: rgba(57, 60, 115),
    800: rgba(28, 30, 59),
    900: rgba(1, 1, 1),
    A100: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.2),
    A200: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.4),
    A400: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.8),
    A700: rgba(57, 60, 115),
    contrast: (50: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        100: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        200: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        300: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        400: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        500: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        600: white,
        700: white,
        800: white,
        900: white,
        A100: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        A200: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        A400: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        A700: white)
);

$accent-palette: (
    50: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.1),
    100: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.2),
    200: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.4),
    300: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.6),
    400: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.8),
    500: rgba(169, 58, 191),
    600: rgb(127, 58, 144),
    700: rgb(85, 44, 97),
    800: rgb(43, 30, 50),
    900: rgb(1, 1, 1),
    A100: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.2),
    A200: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.4),
    A400: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.8),
    A700: rgb(85, 44, 97),
    contrast: (50: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        100: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        200: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        300: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        400: white,
        500: white,
        600: white,
        700: white,
        800: white,
        900: white,
        A100: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        A200: rgb(34, 34, 34),
        A400: white,
        A700: white)
);

$csn-primary: mat.define-palette($primary-palette, 500);
$csn-accent: mat.define-palette($accent-palette, 500, A200, A700);

$csn-theme: mat.define-light-theme((color: (primary: $primary-palette,
                accent: $accent-palette ),
            density: 0,
        ));

$color-config: mat.get-color-config($csn-theme);

@include mat.core-theme($csn-theme);

@include mat.button-theme($csn-theme);

:root {
    --primary: #7178E3;
    --accent: #A83ABF;
    --warn: $mat-red;
    --primaryContrast: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

Here is the styles section of my angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/csn-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

When I try to build the application running ng serve, I receive the following error.

```
./src/csn-theme.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
$color: null is not a color.
  ╷
9 │   --mat-mdc-button-ripple-color: #{rgba($color, 0.1)};
  │                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme-private.scss 9:36    -ripple-color()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme-private.scss 35:5    ripple-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 177:7           @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\mdc-helpers\_mdc-helpers.scss 178:5  @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\mdc-helpers\_mdc-helpers.scss 246:3  disable-mdc-fallback-declarations()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\mdc-helpers\_mdc-helpers.scss 177:3  using-mdc-theme()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 43:3            color()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 216:7           @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 403:3          private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 210:3           theme()
  src\csn-theme.scss 80:1                                                  root stylesheet

./src/csn-theme.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
$color: null is not a color.
  ╷
9 │   --mat-mdc-button-ripple-color: #{rgba($color, 0.1)};
  │                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme-private.scss 9:36    -ripple-color()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme-private.scss 35:5    ripple-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 177:7           @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\mdc-helpers\_mdc-helpers.scss 178:5  @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\mdc-helpers\_mdc-helpers.scss 246:3  disable-mdc-fallback-declarations()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\mdc-helpers\_mdc-helpers.scss 177:3  using-mdc-theme()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 43:3            color()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 216:7           @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 403:3          private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 210:3           theme()
  src\csn-theme.scss 80:1                                                  root stylesheet



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

I am somewhat inexperienced with the syntax of scss, however I am able to determine that the error occurs because the value returned by prop-value function in '@material/theme/theme-color' for the parameter of "primary" is null... and null is not a color.

If I remove `@include mat.button-theme($csn-theme);` from my scss file then the build passes. The problem is generated when trying to configure the ripples styling as part of the button config I think.

Would anyone be able to help me out?

I have tried placing some temporary @debug statements into the node_modules files and was able identify the cause of the problem at the very highest level, but beyond that I don't know what I am doing!

Ultimately I am expecting to have a custom theme configured which uses the 2 colors I have specified in my scss file as the primary and accent colors for all relevant components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide **mat palettes** when creating the mat theme. But you are currently providing your own palette / color description

```css
$primary-colors: (
        50: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.1),
        100: rgba(113, 120, 227, 0.2),
        // etc 
);

$accent-colors: (
        50: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.1),
        100: rgba(169, 58, 191, 0.2),
        // etc
);

$csn-primary-palette: mat.define-palette($primary-colors, 500);
$csn-accent-palette: mat.define-palette($accent-colors, 500, A200, A700);

// provide mat palettes, not the colors
$csn-theme: mat.define-light-theme((color: (primary: $csn-primary-palette,
        accent: $csn-accent-palette ),
        density: 0,
));
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Grogu for talking the time to answer this question. This has solved it for me and I've marked as answer. Looking at it again I think this is a gotcha that I created by trying to write code late at night! I've copied your example and improved my variable naming so that it is more clear what's happening. Kind regards